# Total no of visitors dates wise not getting desired result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to get total number of visitors for each day & order them by date

Below is a sample dates

```
NoOfBooking  VisitDate
2            2014-01-21 11:16:28.490
2            2014-01-20 06:12:46.983
1            2014-01-19 11:28:24.743
2            2014-01-19 02:43:46.867
1            2014-01-18 16:24:25.200
2            2014-01-05 20:20:29.597
2            2014-01-05 16:10:31.760
2            2014-01-02 10:23:52.333
2            2014-01-01 02:30:11.780
2            2013-12-31 10:02:01.083
```

My output is pretty much same may be because of Time stamp with date. How can i only get to  get details based on date only.

T-SQL query

```
SELECT 
   SUM(NoOfBooking) AS Total, VisitDate 
FROM 
   Booking  
GROUP BY  
   NoOfBooking, VisitDate
ORDER BY 
   VisitDate DESC
```

UPDATE: I also tried below it didn't work either.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(NoOfBooking) AS Total, 
    VisitDate 
FROM 
    Booking  
GROUP BY  
    NoOfBooking, CAST(VisitDate AS DATE) 
ORDER BY 
    VisitDate DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
   SELECT SUM(NoOfBooking) AS Total, cast(VisitDate as date) as VisitDate 
   FROM Booking 
   GROUP BY cast(VisitDate as date) 
   order by VisitDate DESC
```

Adding `NoOfBooking` in your `group by` will produce incorrect results...

Answer (score 1):

try this ::

```
  SELECT SUM(NoOfBooking) AS Total, VisitDate 
FROM Booking GROUP BY NoOfBooking,
 date(VisitDate) order by VisitDate DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Cast VisitDate as Date

```
SELECT SUM(NoOfBooking) AS Total, cast(VisitDate as Date) as VisitDate
    FROM Booking  
    GROUP BY  cast(VisitDate as Date)
    order by cast(VisitDate as Date)
```

Comment: if the update you have posted is the exact query you have run, it's because you didn't put `cast(VisitDate as Date)` in your select query, and put `VisitDate` only.

Comment: My Mistake... It Still doesnt get the right data as it still show  2014-01-19 in two rows pretty much same result as i have data.

Comment: because you're using `NoOfBooking` in `group by`

Comment: @MaryamArshi Salams the SUM in select does not do any thing if you use the SUM field in GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Yup I updated my answer, the NoOfbooks should not be in group by

Answer (score 0):

Use the cast function

```
select cast(visitdate as date) visdate, sum(NoOfBooking) total
from booking
group by cast(visitdate as date)
order by visdate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use convert to get only date part.

```
SELECT SUM(NoOfBooking) AS Total, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),VisitDate,111) AS VDATE
FROM   Booking  
GROUP  BY  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),VisitDate,111)
ORDER  BY VisitDateDESC
```